# How to create an object from a java.lang.Class value?

Tags: java, class

```
Class c = Integer.class
```

Say I only have `c` how can I create an `Integer` object from that?

Note that it doesn't necessarily need to be Integer, I'd like to do this for anything.

Comment: In response to a buried comment: Compile-time types are .. compile-time. It is *not possible to declare a variable "of c"* for an arbitrary Class object. You would have to treat the resulting object (however such is obtained) as the most generic covering type (eg. `Object`) and/or specialize-cast as required (eg. `(Integer)i`) and/or use reflection.

Comment: in your comments you always ask for the name of the class - maybe you're looking for `java.lang.Class.getName()` ??

Comment: Start by using [`Class#isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) to determine if the given `Class` can be assigned to a different class type, for example `c.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)`, this will, at least, tell you if the given class or compatible.

Comment: Then use something like [`Class#getConstructor(Class...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-), because `Integer` does not have a default constructor, something like `c.getConstructor(int.class)`.  Use the resulting  `Constructor` to create a new instance of the class, something like `Integer value = (Integer)con.newInstance(42);`

Comment: @Aequitas what integer would you expect to get back?  Most classes don't have a sensible default instance; what would you expect to get back for them?  This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```
Class c = Class.forName("package.SomeClass");//If you have any specific class
```

And then instance :

```
Object obj = c.newInstance();

int intObj = (Integer) obj
```

Comment: `java.lang.InstantiationException ... Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.<init>()`

Comment: Put back what you edited please, this answer actually helped me, thankyou

Comment: For upvoter: `Integer` class has no default constructor, so current code will raise an exception (noted by @MadProgrammer).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but works if there is a default constructor so will work in lots of cases.

Comment: @Aequitas your question is about `Integer`, and this doesn't respond that. Also, this is already covered in the duplicate Q/A, there's no need to repost it here.

Comment: @Aequitas I have changed littile bit code

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ah yes this is a subset of that question, since the first step there is getting the Class which I already have, then I just follow the next two steps like in this answer.

Comment: @Aequitas You seriously don't help the community...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What did I do wrong? I searched for the answer to my question before posting it, I didn't come across that other question because it's asking given a class name string, whereas I was searching for given a Class. I'm sorry that I didn't find the duplicate before I asked, I also asked in the chat before I posted it to see if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use newInstance() method.

```
c.newInstance();
```

Creates exception.

**Output:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.<init>()
```

---

**Update:**

For the class who do not have default (no parameterized) constructor you can not create instance without knowing its type. For others see the below example and its output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class stringClass = String.class;
    Class integerClass = Integer.class;

    try {
        System.out.println(stringClass.getConstructor());
        Object obj = stringClass.newInstance();
        if (obj instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("String object created.");
        }

        System.out.println(integerClass.getConstructor());
        obj = integerClass.newInstance();
        if (obj instanceof Integer) {
            System.out.println("String object created.");
        }

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // You can not create instance as it does not have default constructor.
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
public java.lang.String()
String object created.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at xyz.Abc.main(Abc.java:15)
```

Comment: how would I assign this to an object of Integer? like `c.class integerObject = c.newInstance();`

Comment: It will fail with an `InstantiationException`. The `Integer` class does not have a nullary constructor.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.<init>()`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes, you are right.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since instances of `Integer` class are `immutable`, you need to something like this :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Class<?> c = Integer.class;
    Constructor<?>[] co = c.getDeclaredConstructors(); // get Integer constructors
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(co)); 
    Integer i = (Integer) co[1].newInstance("5"); //call one of those constructors.
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

O/P :

```
[public java.lang.Integer(int), public java.lang.Integer(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException]
5
```

You need to explicitly do these things because `Integer` class does not provide *mutators / default constructor* all we are *initializing* values by using constructor injection.

Comment: Just curious, what does this have to do with the class being `immutable`?

Comment: `co[1]`? Hope all versions of Java has the same constructors in the same sequence.

Comment: Integer *objects* are immutable; but such is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @user2864740 - It is. Since instances of `Integer` class are immutable, they don't have a default public constructor. So, you need to call another one explicitly

Comment: @TheLostMind `Integer` has **2** public constructors.

Comment: @Andreas - My bad. I meant *default* constructor

Comment: @TheLostMind Counter-argument: the default constructor could have initialized to the default/corresponding primitive value. And indeed, this is what happens in C# for the 'equivalent' type where the following is valid and true: `0 == new int()`.

Comment: @Andreas - I was just showing how this could be done. You are right. I should not have used `co[1]`

Comment: @user2864740 - I believe this was done to ensure immutabililty and prevent other classes from extending `Integer` (I know `Integer` is `final`, but by convention classes which should not be extended have either no default constructor or a private one). I actually think java has done a good thing by ensuring that value is not initialized to `0`

Comment: @TheLostMind Again, immutable is *completely unrelated* to not having a default constructor, as I demonstrated. The `int` type in C# is not mutable either. While we can argue if it is 'good' that it doesn't have a default constructor, being of an immutable value does not *prevent* a default constructor.

Comment: @user2864740 - What do you suggest?. Keep it there and make it private?

Comment: @user2864740 - I know immutability does not have to do anything with default constructor (`String` has a public default constructor). I am merely trying to say that the designers of Java did not think that this was a good idea in wrapper classes